# how to pass image collected in file input by url?

Tags: javascript, php, backend

I pick up an image with an input file and I want to pass that image to an .php and then upload the image to a server, the issue is that I want to pass this image through an url, I've been looking for some method to do it but I can not find the way, I do not know if it is possible to pass it alone and only through a URL.
I pick up the image from the local, so the complete route I do not know.

Comment: You can achieve that by doing the following: 
1. Get the posted file 
2. then post it again to any url (as api endpoint post using CURL or some  HTTP Client in PHP)
3. At the API end point you can save the file.

If the file size is large you may have to save it temporarily at the first location.

Comment: you want to upload a fie on the user's computer, correct?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would send the image data in a `POST` request to your php script. If you do the built-in form post without javascript, you'll get what you want automatically, but that ens up reloading the page, so if you don't want to reload the page, then you need to use javascript to send it to your php script.

As mentioned earlier, this is usually done using a 'POST' request, and the image data is sent in the body of that request, not in the url.

It would be possible to send the image data in the url, because you do have access to the image data when the user selects a file. However, there are often limits to the length of urls (depending on many factors: browsers, operating systems, network devices, server software, etc.), so only small images could be sent this way.

Take a look at this code to get an idea of how you can extract the data from an image: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BveGBL?&editable=true

Also look at these docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

So in theory, it is possible to add an image data url to a parameter of your server url, however, it is better to send it in the body of a `POST`, `PUT` or `PATCH` request instead.